# How to detect when user has declined to enable Location Services more than 2 times?

Tags: ios

When calling the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` method of `CLLocationManager`, if the user has disabled Location Services, iOS displays an alert that says:

> Turn On Location Services to Allow "Your App Name" to Determine Your
>   Location

This alert has a Settings button that takes the user to "Location Services" in the Settings app, and a Cancel button.

This alert is great, but the problem I'm having is that it only displays up to 2 times. If the user clicks Cancel both times, then the next time I call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, no alert is displayed.

I would like to at least tell the user what the problem is in this scenario, but I don't know how to detect this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> This alert is great, but the problem I'm having is that it only displays up to 2 times. If the user clicks Cancel both times, then the next time I call requestWhenInUseAuthorization, no alert is displayed.

As you rightly observe, you cannot rely on the system alert. But you don't have to. You can tell whether the user has disabled core location completely by calling the CLLocationManager class method `locationServicesEnabled`. You can then present *your own* alert.

Comment: It is very annoying that you don't have a way to know whether the runtime is going to present the system alert on your behalf; you might want to file a bug report about that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue with presenting my own alert is that then I don't seem to be able to direct the user to the Location Services view in the Settings app.

Comment: Yes, that’s a pity. But you can take the user to you app settings at least. As I said, file a bug on all this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the number of authorization requests yourself. 
The simplest way would be to use UserDefaults. Like this:

**Save value:**

`UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "DidRequestAuthorization")`

**Load value:**

`let didRequestAuthorization = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "DidRequestAuthorization")`

Then if `didRequestAuthorization`is true you can display an alert next time that warns the user to cancel the request.

Comment: He's not talking about user authorization. He's talking about Core Location _itself_ being turned off.

Comment: This is an approach I considered. It doesn't seem very robust, but perhaps it's the best one can do.

Comment: @matt I understood that when we call requestWhenInUseAuthorization we want to know if we already tried asking the user twice. If that is the case the system alert will not be shown anymore so we want to notifiy the user with our own alert that he/she might have to enable Location Services. So we need to somehow save the amount of times we already tried it. But I agree with you, using "locationServicesEnabled" is better then my approach.